# Save checkboxes with a foreach loop for all registered posts types [Plugin Development]

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am new to wordpress plugin development. Here I want an user to check his/her required post types from all the registered post types listed in checkbox. This code below show all the registered posts types with checkbox but when a user checks the box and save changes, the page refreshes but the checkbox isn't checked.

```html
function fbog_options_page() {

    add_submenu_page(
     'tools.php',
        'FB Custom Open Graph',
        'FB Custom Open Graph',
        'manage_options',
        'cpn-fbog-settings',
        'cpn_fbog_options_page_html',
        20
    );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'fbog_options_page' );





function cpn_fbog_settings(){
 register_setting('fbog_settings_group', 'fbog_settings');
}
add_action('admin_init', 'cpn_fbog_settings');




function cpn_fbog_options_page_html(){
 global $fbog_options;

 $fbog_options = get_option('fbog_settings');
 
 ob_start();
?>
 <div class="wrap">
  <div class="container">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
     <center><h1>Welcome to Custom Facebook Open Graph</h1></center>

     <h3>Choose the post types to display the "Custom Facebook Open Graph".</h3>
     
     <form method="post" action="options.php">
 
      <?php settings_fields('fbog_settings_group'); ?>
    
      <h4>Check the Post Types</h4>
      <p>
       <?php
        $post_types = get_post_types();
       foreach ($post_types as $post_type) {
       ?>
       <input id="fbog_settings_<?php echo $post_type; ?>" name="fbog_settings[post_types]" type="checkbox" value="1"<?php checked( 1, $fbog_options['post_types'], false ); ?> />
       <label class="description" for="fbog_settings[post_types]"><?php _e($post_type, 'fbog_domain'); ?></label>
       <br />
       <?php
        }
       ?>
      </p>
    
      <p class="submit">
       <input type="submit" class="button-primary" value="<?php _e('Save Options', 'fbog_domain'); ?>" />
      </p>
    
     </form>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div> 
<?php
echo ob_get_clean();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code is right except you are not saving the right post type.
change this line:

```
<input id="fbog_settings_<?php echo $post_type; ?>" name="fbog_settings[<?= $post_type ?>]" type="checkbox" value="1"<?php checked( 1, @$fbog_options[$post_type]); ?> />
```